# compare string with * character javascript

Tags: javascript, string

Is it possible to compare strings like this?:

```
string1 = "ABC/DEF/GHI/*"
string2 = "ABC/DEF/GHI/JKL/MNO"

if (string1 == string2){
  //do sth 
}
```

I mean - the `*` character on the end of `string1`. In some web searchers we use the `*` or `?`, is it possible in comparing strings?

Comment: If you're referring to the [glob pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29), then no, JS has no equivalent. You can do similar things (and more!) with regexes, though

Answer (score 1):

Not using the `==` sign. If you remove the `*` you can use `indexOf`

```
var string1 = "ABC/DEF/GHI/";
var string2 = "ABC/DEF/GHI/JKL/MNO";

if (string2.indexOf(string1)>=0){
  //do sth 
}
```